# Ansible - check if item is in the list

Tags: ansible

I want to compare two lists - one with all available options, and the second one is with specific options to be selected.
For example, I have two lists:

```
FullList:
  - name: "Test1"
    value1: "blabla123"
    value2: "someothervalue"
  - name: "Test2"
    value1: "blsdfsdfasfabla"
    value2: "someothervalue"
  - name: "Test3"
    value1: "sdjfbhsadbfv"
    value2: "someothervalue"
  - name: "Test4"
    value1: "sdjkfnsjkf"
    value2: "sdjkfnsjkf"
```

It contains all available elements with their properties.

And I have the second list with specific keys to select items from the full list.

```
List1:
  - "Test2"
  - "Test3"
```

I want to get elements from FullList, that I have in List1

i.e. I expect

```
Result:
  - name: "Test2"
    value1: "blsdfsdfasfabla"
    value2: "someothervalue"
  - name: "Test3"
    value1: "sdjfbhsadbfv"
    value2: "someothervalue"
```

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 12):

Use the [filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#filters) *selectattr* and [test](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#tests) *in*. For example,

```yaml
  Result: "{{ FullList|selectattr('name', 'in', List1) }}"
```

gives the expected result

```yaml
  Result:
    - {name: Test2, value1: blsdfsdfasfabla, value2: someothervalue}
    - {name: Test3, value1: sdjfbhsadbfv, value2: someothervalue}
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all
  
  vars:

    FullList:
      - {name: Test1, value1: blabla123, value2: someothervalue}
      - {name: Test2, value1: blsdfsdfasfabla, value2: someothervalue}
      - {name: Test3, value1: sdjfbhsadbfv, value2: someothervalue}
      - {name: Test4, value1: sdjkfnsjkf, value2: sdjkfnsjkf}      
    List1: [Test2, Test3]

    Result: "{{ FullList|selectattr('name', 'in', List1) }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: Result|to_yaml
      run_once: true
```

Answer (score 7):

Please try as below to print

```
  tasks:
  - debug:
     msg : "{{ item }}"
    when: item.name in List1
    loop: "{{FullList}}"
```

To save to a variable use as below

```
  - name: test
    set_fact:
     test: "{{ item }}"
    when: item.name in List1
    loop: "{{FullList}}"
```